# curl to xively using python

Tags: python, curl, xively

I'm looking to push json packets to xively using this command:

```
jstr = '''{ "version":"1.0.0", "datastreams":[{"id":"one","current_value":"100.00"},{"id":"two","current_value":"022.02"},{"id":"three","current_value":"033.03"},{"id":"four","current_value":"044.04"}] }'''
```

and running it by calling this:

```
cmd = "curl --request PUT %s --header %s --verbose %s" % (jstr,apiKey,feedId)
```

I'm doing it this way so I can manipulate the JSON between transmissions (I change it to a dict and back).

It's throwing an error saying that there is no data sent. I'm new to curl, xively and python so it's really confusing me. Any help would be greatly appreciated please.

Comment: you probably need to escape it somehow

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this will be using [official Python module](http://xively.github.io/xively-python/) provided by Xively.

Here are few reasons for not doing it the way you just described:

1. the official library provides a nice and simple API
2. you don't need to care what the data format actually is
3. calling curl command to make an HTTP request every 
   time is absolutely inefficient as it take time for the OS
   to spawn and new process